# How to use setRecommendedGlobalProxy in android

Tags: android, proxy, android-5.0-lollipop, device-owner

I am trying to use setRecommendedGlobalProxy for android. You can find the documentation [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setRecommendedGlobalProxy(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.net.ProxyInfo))

I understand that it takes inputs, host, port and list of URLs to block, however when I used it, all network on my device stopped working. So I did end up breaking my HTTP which is not what I want.

I want to be able to block specific websites (inappropriate for school environment).

Do I have to setup a proxy server? But the documentation states that it is network independent.

I already have device owner. Please note, I cannot use any kind of root method.

Purpose of using the proxy: I want to block inappropriate content from devices, when used in school.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to setup a proxy server?

Yes, you will need to setup a proxy server.

The [setRecommendedGlobalProxy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setRecommendedGlobalProxy(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.net.ProxyInfo)) function requires a [ProxyInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ProxyInfo.html) parameter which is used to provide the proxy host, port, etc... you plan to proxy all http/https traffic to. The documentation states that the proxy is network independent which only means that no matter what wifi/cellular network the device is connected to, http/https traffic will always be proxified.

Set the global proxy to a proxy you know is working and your http shouldn't break anymore. Then, go to your proxy and block the unwanted websites.

Here's an example in case you need it.

```
ProxyInfo myProxy = ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy("host-name.com", port);

    try {

        mDPM.setRecommendedGlobalProxy(adminComponent, myProxy);

    } catch (SecurityException e) {

        Log.w("ERROR!", "Caught exception while setting global proxy: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

**Note**: I realize this is an old question but figured I'd respond for the sake of anyone else who comes along.

Comment: Any idea how to set the username and password for global proxy setting?

Comment: @madawa try something like `http://username:password@hostname.com:port`. If that doesn't work let me know. It's been a little while since I tried this. But I know it's possible.

Comment: I tried above but seems it doesn't work. Works when there's no username and password but when the username and password are added, the proxy is not picking up. Any idea why?